# Angular directive for inputs that allows to select a value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive, ngx-bootstrap

In my Angular app, I need to create a custom [directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) that I will attach to my Reactive Form's inputs.

Such directive should behave like this:

- When the user clicks on the input, **a panel** should appear below the input.
- In such panel, there will be something that allows the user to select some value (e.g. checkboxes, radio buttons, etc...). Somehow the current value of the control input should be passed to such panel in order to **reflect the current selection**. Eventually I will need several types of such directive with different contents in the appearing panel, so I want to **reuse as much code as possible**.
- When the user selects the value, the panel should disappear and the value of the control input should be updated (according to what the user has selected).

[image: example input directive selection]

A good example of what I'm trying to accomplish is the [Datepicker from ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker). In my case, I just want something different than the calendar to be displayed to the user.

What is the best way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: could you please tell me did my answer helped?

Comment: Could you tell me is your problem solved or you sitll want code in plain javascript only?

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI as I commented before in your answer, I don't think using jQuery in an Angular project is a good idea. About my issue specifically, I went for a different approach that didn't involve directives for input (the solution to my specific problem has a completely different approach so it doesn't make sense to share it here). However it would be nice if someone can post an answer to my question with a proper Angular solution. I thank you very much for your help anyway